# android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
   at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ReceiverRestrictedContext.java:141)
   at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ReceiverRestrictedContext.java:130)
   at xxxxx.z$d.invoke(z.java:10)
   at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(ThreadsKt.java:2)
```

In My app we are using [SMS Retrieval API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) for AUTO Read OTP, and we are registering Broadcast receiver once trigger sms api get success response. It is working as expected but when we are checking [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and google play console reporting as Fatal Exception (Crash) with above Stack trace for some cases. We are not able to understand what is the exact root cause and not sure whether it is our Broadcast Receiver or something else and in the logs not showing anything related our code reference.

**For your reference below snippet using for registering broadcast receiver**

```
   val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
   intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
   activity.applicationContext.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter)
   val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(activity.applicationContext)
   client.startSmsRetriever()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `LocalBroadcastManager` method register receiver or sends broadcasts to receivers that are in the same app as the sender

**Register a reciever:**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                     .registerReceiver(mReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(ACTION_CUSTOM_BROADCAST));
```

**Send BroadCast:**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                     .sendBroadcast(new IntentFilter(ACTION_CUSTOM_BROADCAST));
```

**source:** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#sending-broadcasts